# Stop GcmListenerService progmatically

Tags: android, service, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM. I want to stop GcmListenerService so I can stop Application from receiving unwanted notification.

I have tried the below to close the service but it doesn't seems to workout

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyGcmListenerService.class);
stopService(intent);
```

Here is my service class

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService
{

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        String duration = data.getString("duration");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        sendNotification(message,duration);
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    private void sendNotification(String message, String duration) {

        new DisplayNotification(this).makeGCMNotification("Event Name", "Event Start Time", 1);
    }
}
```

and in manifest

```
<service
            android:name=".Utilities.GCM.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: I simply don't want to receive notification at some point in app. Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Stopping the service won't help because the GCMReceiver will always call `startWakefulService` whenever a new message comes in. Since the GCMReceiver class is not really something we're supposed to edit, I suggest that you keep a boolean or set a preference to know when received messages should actually be read/processed. Based on this, you can let the messages get received in the background while actually doing nothing in the app/foreground.

Comment: Thanks :) and I thought this method. But I think this wont be a actual appropriate method to stop receiving push notification.Can you tell Is there any possible way that I can unregistered a device from GCM server itself. ?

Comment: Given that it's your server sending the messages, you could make an http request or send an upstream message telling your server to stop sending to this device. A more brute force way is to call deleteToken()

Answer (score 1):

You can unsubscribe from GCM with two methods: `deleteToken()` and `deleteInstanceID()`. Both approaches generate IOExceptions so they must be handled as well.

Please look at [the "Unregistration and Unsubscription" section](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration).